# Python-binance in AWS Lambda issue: Unable to import module ... No module named 'regex._regex'

Tags: python, regex, aws-lambda, serverless, binance

I'm trying to run an AWS lambda function to retrieve latest crypto prices using `python-binance`. Everything works fine when using VS Code locally, but when I deploy it (with serverless or zip), I get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handlers/action': No module named 'regex._regex'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

For optimization purposes, I attach a layer to the lambda function in order to use Pandas.

Tests:

- Deployed lambda function with both `python-binance` and `pandas` whilst specifying versions.
- Tried `python-binance --no-binary :all:` but got a complain from `servleress`

I don't understand why that would work locally, but not on AWS. Checking online, no one has addressed this issue directly, but there are discussions around Windows vs Linux (I'm using Windows)

**requirements.txt**

```
python-binance
```

**imports**

```
# IMPORTS
import pandas as pd
import math
from binance.client import Client
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
```

**Environment Information**

```
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.18.3
     Framework Version:         1.79.0
     Plugin Version:            3.7.1
     SDK Version:               2.3.1
     Components Version:        2.34.7
```